# Is PVC tubing a good material for helicopter airframes?

Tags: helicopter, ultralight, homebuilt

Been thinking of getting into the hobby of building ultralight helicopters, and would PVC tubing be a good choice to build the overall airframe?

Comment: Not only is the strength to weight ratio poor, PVC also has a rather low modulus, so the airframe will resonate at a multitude of frequencies. While tolerable in a glider, in a helicopter this is unwise. The resonance with all that is vibrating in a helicopter will shake the airframe apart before first flight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The strength to weight ratio of PVC is [poor](https://www.makeitfrom.com/compare/6061-T6-Aluminum/Plasticized-Flexible-Polyvinyl-Chloride-PVC-P) compared to aluminum and you would end up with a very heavy, albeit cheap, machine, and will be even worse when compared to [carbon fibre](https://dragonplate.com/carbon-fiber-tubes) tubing, which would be the optimal choice performance-wise.  Extruded aluminum tubing would likely be the best choice cost wise.  Forget about building a plumb-O-copter.

Comment: If you're talking about the sort of PVC tubing used for irrigation systems, not only is it not very strong, it's also quite flexible.  Hold a 10-ft length (standard size in US hardware stores) in the middle, and it will deflect at least 6" on either end.

Comment: I think he has in mind Sched 40 or Sched 80 rigid plumbing pipe.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (I'm no expert), schedule 40 PVC is the white pipe commonly used for irrigation &c.

Comment: Sched 40 is the standard PVC for residential house plumbing, good for a 2 or 3 hundred psi burst.  Schedule 80 is for higher pressure applications and has nearly double the wall thickness (smaller ID).

Comment: Sure, but bursting strength is not really what's important in building airframes :-)

Comment: I'm just describing what sched 40 and 80 are. If I was going to build something structural that was non-helicopter-y  from PVC from Home Depot, that would be it.

Comment: About the only thing structural I'd build with PVC is the frame that keeps the (very light) bird netting off my strawberries :-)

Answer (score 1):

PVC is no where near stiff enough for a given weight. And its strength to weight ratio is poor. The structural efficiency of air machines is absolutely critical otherwise you are building a machine that may not fly at all.

Plus, do a search for helicopter ground resonance, especially watch some youtube videos of helicopters destroying themselves.

Comment: Ground resonance only comes into play when the helicopter has a rough landing. With PVC tubing it will resonate so much that it will be shaken to pieces even before first flight.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen videos of ground resonance without a preceding landing of any sort 

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using PVC to build scale models, PVC doesn't make a good construction material:

1. it's too flexible. PVC pipe will bend under its own weight.
2. the glue typically used to join PVC is pretty weak, impact loads will break the bond.

Answer (score -3):

PVC pipes are strong and flexible. 1 1/2" diameter pipe type SDR-26 is thinner-walled and weighs only .3 pounds per foot! That's three pounds per ten-foot length which only costs eight dollars each at Home Depot. PVC cement can form a solid integrated bond when applied thickly and left on for ten seconds to melt the surface before mating.
However, PVC is breakable when bent, so the airframe must have a lot of reinforcement braces to reduce the amount of bending of longer sections.
Strength-TEST.!!  Test test, the strength of every section using sandbags. Get an EAA member to advise you on this.
Regarding self-bendability: I just tested a 10' length of 1 1/2" PVC type SDR-26 plastic pipe and when suspended it at center and each end drooped down 1/2" is all. I doubt that any ultralight designer would incorporate any unbraced pipe lengths longer than 2'.

Comment: I have removed your "signature" twice now. Please do not add it again or we'll have to consider you a spammer.